# Make mongo stop throwing errors related to unsupported text index language

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a text index on a collection. I added a `language` field to my documents, and all of a sudden started receiving a bunch of `"language override unsupported: <LANG>"` errors. Apparently `language` is a magical field when you have a text index.

How do I make mongo not throw an error if the language is unsupported? 
It doesn't matter to me if a language is unsupported. I want my insert operation to succeed, regardless if the language is supported or not.

The insert operation:

```js
// This should succeed regardless if suggestion.language is an unsupported language
// I don't want to wrap this in a try/catch, and have to retry on error.
addSuggestion (suggestion) {
    const suggCol = db.get().collection('suggestions')
    return suggCol.insertOne(suggestion)
},
```

How I create my index

```js
// Create a text index, on the "text" property.
// TODO: Mongo throws error if suggestion.language contains an
// unsupported language. Override the language for now.
db.collection('suggestions').createIndex({ text: 'text' }, { language_override: 'dummyVal' })
```

To avoid the error for now, I'm ignoring the text index by setting `{ language_override: 'dummyVal' }`. In the future, I would like to use the language_override.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a feature](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/) and you seem to have already arrived at the correct solution - `language_override`.

Comment: setting `language_override` is a temporary fix to silence the error. eventually, i **do** want to specify a language override, per document. But !!, if the language is unsupported, i don't want mongo to throw an error, it should just ignore the unsupported lang. thats the gist of my question.

Comment: If I am understanding the situation correctly, you should not specify MongoDB language overrides for languages that MongoDB does not support. If you have some other system that understands a different set of languages, use two separate fields - one for MongoDB and one for other system(s).

Comment: I have another system that provides the language value, which may or may not be supported by mongo. So, before every insert, I have to check if the language is supported. if not, I need to move the value to another field, like `language2` or w/e, so mongo doesn't complain? There's no way to tell mongo to not throw an error?

Comment: Looking at server source, it appears to be so. If you believe you have a use case for the server ignoring invalid language values, you may consider filing a [server ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER).